# Why I receive "too many documents writes sent to bulkwriter" when using the 'serverTimestamp' tag?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, bulk

- I wanted to test the `batch` use case and I'm a bit confused.
  Initially I've used the `Batch()` method from the firestore GO SDK. When I use this method I don't receive any error.
- I've seen a message on my IDE when I was using `Batch()`:

  `Deprecated: The WriteBatch API has been replaced with the transaction and the bulk  writer API. For atomic transaction operations, use Transaction. For bulk read and write operations, use BulkWriter.`
- By reading the message I started using the `BulkWriter` but when I'm using it I receive an error:

  ***`too many document writes sent to bulkwriter`***
- When I remove the `serverTimestamp` there is no error.

The code:

```golang
// Storer persists tickets in Firestore.
type Storer struct {
    client *firestore.Client
}

// createTicket contains the data needed to create a Ticket in Firestore.
type createTicket struct {
        Title       string    `firestore:"title"`
        Price       float64   `firestore:"price"`
        DateCreated time.Time `firestore:"dateCreated,serverTimestamp"`
    }

func (s *Storer) CreateTicket(ctx context.Context, ticket tixer.Ticket) error {
    bulk := s.client.BulkWriter(ctx)

    ticketRef := s.client.Collection("tickets").Doc(ticket.ID.String())
    _, err := bulk.Create(ticketRef, createTicket{
        Title: ticket.Title,
        Price: ticket.Price,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    bulk.Flush()

    return nil
}
```